# How to use aws package in a PHP project without using composer?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php

I have a plain PHP project which used composer to install packages but the composer.json file doesn't exist anymore. The vendor folder contains all the currently used packages and the autoload.php file.

Now I need to install and use [aws package](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) but once I run the composer require command, all old packages get removed from the vendor. And when I restore them from a backup, they don't work. The app doesn't recognize them anymore.

How to use the aws package or any other package in such a situation?
Here's the `app/init.php` file of the project (not all of it)

```
define('ROOT_PATH', realpath(__DIR__ . '/..') . '/');
const APP_PATH = ROOT_PATH . 'app/';
const PLUGINS_PATH = ROOT_PATH . 'plugins/';
const THEME_PATH = ROOT_PATH . 'themes/altum/';
......
OTHER LOGIC AND CONSTANTS HERE
......
require_once APP_PATH . 'helpers/Affiliate.php';
/* Autoload for vendor */
require_once ROOT_PATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

I tried to download the folder of aws and copy it to the vendor folder then in the PHP file:

```
use Altum\Middlewares\Csrf;
use Altum\Title;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
```

But I get an error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Altum\Controllers\Aws\S3\S3Client' not found
```

Comment: composer.json is mandatory to use composer

Comment: Yes I know so I'm asking how to use it in such a project which used composer but the file doesn't exist anymore!

Comment: I guess you'll need to recreate the composer.json, like, set up a new project and subsequently add all the components of your original project

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one composer configuration per project. This is not the standard setup, but it is possible. And in your case, it is even helping you with your problem, as you do not need to recover the old composer.json file right now.

Instead the loss of the composer.json file is ignored and the vendor is kept. That is:

The **first composer configuration** you have is the now previous one, the one you've lost the *composer.json* file for. But you still have the `vendor` folder including all dependencies and the metadata like `vendor/composer/installed.json`. As you've lost the *composer.json* file, you should now store the `vendor` folder entirely. If you're using git, you may want to review your `.gitignore` file and replace the `/vendor/` entry with `/vendor-aws/` so that the previous vendor folder is no longer ignored and you can put all dependencies under configuration management as a git subtree.

The **second composer coniguration** is the one that we're gonna create. It's near default, just the vendor directory <sup>1</sup> is different. Instead of the default name `vendor` we call it `vendor-aws`. And we add the autoloader <sup>2</sup> from the *first composer configuraiton*, as the second configuration inherits the first:

```json
{
  "autoload": {
    "files": ["vendor/autoload.php"]
  }
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "vendor-aws"
  } 
}
```

Validate this new `composer.json` file and commit it. Afterwards require the aws and other packages whatever you wish.

Send your new configuration into test and integrate it and perhaps already works.

This should continue to work until the old vendor remains unmaintainable. But until then you've likely added all dependencies new and again to the new composer configuration file and build back the vendor folder switch.

Remember that `vendor/composer/installed.json` still gives you the list of what was installed so you still need to identify the main packages (as that list contains *all* packages including dependencies) but you can easily test by require/remove them in the new configuration.

---

1. https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir
2. https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload